# javascript closure __proto__

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype

```
function makeAdder(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}
var add5 = makeAdder(5);
add5(2); //7;
add5(2).__proto__;  //0`
```

It makes sense. However, add5(2) is object? Why is there an 0?

Comment: What do you mean by there? According to my chrome dev tools, `__proto__` is an object, not 0.

Comment: Everything in JS (except `undefined` and `null`) is an object.

Comment: Open a new Chrome tab pointing to about:blank and try on a new/clear console. You should see that add5(2).__proto__ is a non-zero Number object.

Comment: @jmargolisvt: No. All primitive values (which includes strings, numbers, booleans and symbols) are not objects.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Run this `typeof null` you will get `object`.

Comment: You should get the same output with `(7).__proto__`. This has nothing to do with the function calls or the usage of a closure.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak: That doesn't make `null` an object. That's simply how `typeof` works (unfortunately).

Comment: @FelixKling Completely agree with you (and also agree about primitives) but here I just try to say that statement `everything in JS is an object` is wrong.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak: Sure, but `null` seems to be the wrong argument for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which environment you are running the code in, but this is what happens when you trying to access `__proto__` on a **number value**: The value is temporarily converted to a number *object* (i.e. equivalent to calling `new Number(7)`). The prototype of that object is of course `Number.prototype`.

[The spec says](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-properties-of-the-number-prototype-object):

> The Number prototype is itself a Number object; it has a [[NumberData]] internal slot with the value +0.

I can only assume that the environment you are using detects that `add5(2).__proto__` is a number object and calls its `valueOf` method, which then returns `0`:

```js
console.log(Number.prototype.valueOf());
```

Comment: Thanks. Are parameters in the function seen in javascript in compiler time? I mean in the scope the parameter is created as a variable.